Connection to MongoDB cluster getting failed through NodeJS
Issue I am facing
I am working on the ExpressJS web services project. We have created a free cluster in MongoDB Atlas and I am trying to connect to the DB using the connection string provided by the website itself. I have whitelisted my own IP and made it accessible from anywhere as well but still nothing has worked yet. To what I think my code is okay as I was able to connect to the localhost database. But I am still mentioning it below for better review.
The code:
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const port = 8000;

// Encode username and password for mongodb as URI encoded component
const username = encodeURIComponent("<username>");
const password = encodeURIComponent("<password>")

// const mongoDbUrl = `mongodb://${username}:${password}@host:port/database`;
// const mongoDbUrl = `mongodb://${username}:${password}@diversity-of-living-clu.hqwcott.mongodb.net`;
const mongoDbUrl = "mongodb://<username>:<password>@diversity-of-living-clu.hqwcott.mongodb.net/"

// mongodb://<username>:<password>@diversity-of-living-clu.hqwcott.mongodb.net/3380DiversityOfLiving-data?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=diversity-of-living-cluster
// Initialising options for cors
const corsOptions = {
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true
}

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Routers
const numbeoRouter = require('./DiversityOfLiving-Routers/NumbeoRouterAra65');
const userRouter = require('./DiversityOfLiving-Routers/UserRouterJpa72');
const faqRouter = require('./DiversityOfLiving-Routers/FAQRouterJpa72');
const countryCountRouter = require('./DiversityOfLiving-Routers/CountryCountRouterJpa72');
const countryDataRouter = require('./DiversityOfLiving-Routers/CountryDataRouterAra65');

// Using Routers
app.use('/numbeo', numbeoRouter);
app.use('/faq', faqRouter);
app.use('/countrycount', countryCountRouter);
app.use('/user', userRouter);
app.use('/countrydata', countryDataRouter);

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on: http://localhost:' + port);
    mongoose.connect(mongoDbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, connectTimeoutMS: 10000 })
    .then(() => {console.log("Connected to MongoDB");})
    .catch((err) => {console.log("Error connecting to MongoDB:", err.message, err.stack);})
});

The solutions that I have tried:

Both SRV and Non-SRV URLs
Whitelisted my IP and made it available from anywhere as well.

The below is the error that I am getting:
Error connecting to MongoDB: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/ MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

But I do not think that is the issue as I was able to connect to the cluster using my MongoDB Compass, Mongosh and VS Code MongoDB extension.
Open to any reviews to the code and to try new solutions as well. Thank you!

If you use mongodb+srv:// instead of mongodb:// the driver should be able to find the DNS host of your Atlas cluster. Also, on free tiers your cluster gets paused due to inactivity so make sure that hasn't happened. Why are you using encodeURIComponent, do you have special characters in the username and password? The useNewUrlParser and useUnifiedTopology options are deprecated if you are using mongoose version 6+.

I see, it's giving an issue because I am using the old of Mongoose. I updated both the package and the updated the url as well. It gets connected to the cluster but this was an old project and now I'll have to change the other code of my application as well.

It's important to keep the packages in your app updated, primarily for security patches but as you've found out - compatibility issues also arise. Good luck with the upgrade.

It is giving me another warning (node:33066) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The "punycode" module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.. What could be causing this?

Resolved - I just manually updated the "punycode" package

Solution involves two steps

Updating the mongoose package manually. I had the old mongoose package involved which was depreciated.

npm install mongoose@latest

OR (to specify the version)
npm install mongoose@8.4.0


Using mongodb+srv:// instead of mongodb:// in the url to connect to the MongoDB cluster


I had the same problem while using Node 19.6.0.
I resolved it by upgrading Node to the latest version.

I think you need to change the network access IP to
0.0.0.0/0
for your MongoDB Atlas cluster under security section. It should work fine. If not, try connecting your system to your mobile hotspot. Sometimes, there are network barriers that prevent the server from accessing the IP address.

Instead of granting access from any IP one should better grant access from IP which are really needed.

I have already whitelisted my IP Address, i have mentioned this in my question. The issue is resolved that was not the issue.
